# Where is the star button at the left of a question title?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-interface, bookmarks

On Stack Exchange websites there happens to be a ☆ button for **mark a question as favourite**. But I couldn't find it in the app. Where is it located. My app is of the latest version. It is a useful feature to be in the app.